# JSON.net parse working local but not on the server (LDAP issue)

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, ldap, json.net

Like the title says the code I have currently works just fine local and brings back all the results. However, running the same code on the server only finds half of the data (its the same data both ways)

The code is:

```
Private Sub workingGetFEBList()
    Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(apiURL & appID & "/" & formID & "?format=text/xml")

    request.Method = "GET"
    request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials

    Dim response1 As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
    Dim dataStream As Stream = response1.GetResponseStream()
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
    Dim serverResponse As String = reader.ReadToEnd()

    reader.Close()
    dataStream.Close()
    response1.Close()

    Dim theOutput As String = parseXML2JSON(serverResponse)

    pageData = theOutput
End Sub

Private Function parseXML2JSON(ByVal theXML As String) As String
    doc.LoadXml(theXML)
    jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc)
    jsreader = New JsonTextReader(New StringReader(jsonText))
    json = DirectCast(New JsonSerializer().Deserialize(jsreader), JObject)

    For Each Row In json("data")("metadata")("elementType")
       Try
            result_RowNames(intX) = NullSafeSelect(Row, "name")
            result_RowProperNames(intX) = NullSafeSelect(Row, "label")
            intX += 1
       Catch ex As NullReferenceException
            intX = 0
            Exit For
       End Try
    Next
End Function
```

The above code works fine for both local and server. The code below only seems to work on local and not the server:

```
Try
   For Each Row In json("data")("records")("F_Form1")
       Try
           For rowNum = 0 To result_RowNames.Length - 1
               result_rowData(intX) = NullSafeSelect(Row, result_RowNames(rowNum))
               intX += 1
           Next
       Catch ex As NullReferenceException
           intX = 0
           Exit For
       End Try
   Next

   If intX <> 0 Then ReDim Preserve result_rowData(intX - 1)
Catch ex As Exception
   Response.Write("ERROR: " & ex.Message & vbCrLf & json.ToString)
End Try
```

On the server, once that call is made, results in this error:

> ERROR: Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue. {
>   "data": { "recordCount": "0", "metadata": { "elementType": [ { "name":
>   "F_FName", "uiType": "textField", "dataType": "string", "label":
>   "First Name", "dataLabel": "" }, { "name": "F_LName", "uiType":
>   "textField", "dataType": "string", "label": "Last Name", "dataLabel":
>   "" } ] }, "records": null } }

The XML looks like this (and again, its the same call on local and server):

```
<data>
   <recordCount>13</recordCount>
   <metadata>
       <elementType>
           <name>F_FName</name>
           <uiType>textField</uiType>
           <dataType>string</dataType>
           <label>First Name</label>
           <dataLabel/>
       </elementType>
       <elementType>
            <name>F_LName</name>
            <uiType>textField</uiType>
            <dataType>string</dataType>
            <label>Last Name</label>
            <dataLabel/>
       </elementType>
   </metadata>
   <records>
       <F_Form1 application_uid="22f48e69ce11" draft_ownerid="" flowState="NewStageName" has_draft="" id="5" uid="25550af04b9f">
           <F_FName>bart</F_FName>
           <F_LName>simpson</F_LName>
       </F_Form1>
       <F_Form1 application_uid="22f48e69ce11" draft_ownerid="" flowState="NewStageName" has_draft="" id="6" uid="c47fe41feeca">
           <F_FName>New</F_FName>
           <F_LName>Record</F_LName>
       </F_Form1>
       ....etc etc.....
   </records>
</data>
```

I'm seeing from the XML output it says **"recordCount": "0"** when on my local it says **"recordCount": "13"** so I am thinking its due to networking authorization?

Seems **** works just fine on local while it doesn't work on the server? What would the equivalent be for it to work on the server **without** having to put a username and password in the code? The server is using **active directory/LDAP** in order to know whos logged into any page.

Comment: I would get Wireshark installed on that target server to check the LDAP authorization with Active Directory, which typically will occur over port 636 for LDAPS , or port 389 for LDAP. You can filter by those so you can see the exact traffic you're looking for.

Comment: @X3074861X thanks for the suggestion... however, even with filtering it i had no idea what i was looking for.

Comment: Ah, yes I should have detailed that as well. First, make sure you're at least successfully connecting to active directory from that server. Once the connection takes place, look for a `Bind` request from your target server, which is what authorizes the current principal context against active directory. If the bind works, you should see a follow up sequence detailing as such, and if not, you'll see a bind failure attempt.